# Force Spring/JPA/Hibernate/JDBC to retry a failed beginTransaction?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, jdbc, c3p0

Sometimes a db transaction can't begin because of a simple SocketException when trying to reach MySQL. In the current codebase, all SQL or JPQL code resides in classes with the @Transactional annotation  (org.springframework.transaction.annotation). A transaction is created for me for each method call to an annotated class. This makes it difficult to write code that can be reused across all db calls.

One solution would be to put the db code within a loop: It will retry the transaction a few times. This works but I'd prefer not to sprinkle my code full of loops (one for each db call).

Is their a way to make either one of the following frameworks retry a failed beginTransaction automatically?: Spring, JPA, Hibernate, c3p0, MySQL JDBC driver

For reference, here is a piece of the log:

```
java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Connection reset

STACKTRACE:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:113)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:160)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:188)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1910)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2304)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2803)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1665)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3170)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:5273)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:881)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1353)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:38)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:52)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:330)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:374)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:263)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
```

PS. I hate automagic frameworks that supposedly solve all problems. It wasn't my decision to make in this project.

Comment: You say the code is already creating too many transactions, and retrying will create more. Seems like it's time to fix how the app does transactions.

Comment: I don't know what you're using for a datasource but you might be able to solve this problem with configuration around how connections are borrowed. For example, apache commons BasicDataSource has testOnBorrow, validationQuery and removeAbandoned to help make sure you get a valid connection to begin with.  http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html

Comment: If I get the chance to redo transaction handling, I will drop Spring altogether and go directly to JPA (or even better: JDBC).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to bring retry loops into your code, perhaps you can use AOP to implement retry functionality. There is an [example](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-example) of such an advice in Spring documentation.

Comment: No, you can specify the ```order``` of the advice to happen before or after the existing transaction advice (depending on if you want to retry within an existing transaction, or start a new one every time you retry).

Answer (score 0):

Create a utility method that takes a [TransactionCallback](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionCallback.html) as a parameter.   In that method do the looping and exception handling, using a [TransactionTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html).

When you need to run a query with retries use this method.

See the [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-prog-template) for details.

For example, your calling code would look like:

```
public Object someServiceMethod() {
  return yourUtilityObj.retry(new TransactionCallback() {

    public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
      updateOperation1();
      return resultOfUpdateOperation2();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You're suggesting that I use manual transaction handling. Maybe that is the way to go. I was hoping for a simple retry=true flag...

Comment: That would be a great enhancement to @Transaction!  Vote on https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5890